# Read an InputStream from a URL and Write to HttpServletResponse without creating a temp file

Tags: java

I tried to read an InputStream from a URL and write to HttpServletResponse directly without creating a temporary file in an HttpServlet, but failed to get real Content-Length of the file. I've been told that I can't determine the amount of data in a stream without reading it. Can someone help me? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The length of the file is different than the content-length the server you are reading from gives you?

Comment: It's the same. But calling inputStream.available() does not return the real length of the file and calling response.setHeader("Content-Length", length) after writing data to OutputStream does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are reading from a URL, you should have the length available from the `Content-length` header of that URL.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
if ( connection.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
    response.setContentLength( contentLength );
```

Note that you should **not** use `inputStream.available()`. The `available()` method merely tells you how many bytes can be read without blocking (that is, waiting for the next chunk to arrive from the network). It does not tell you the size of the stream! But in an `HttpURLConnection`, you can get the value of the content-length header using the `getContentLength()` method.

Once you do that, you can start a read-write loop to copy all the data, e.g.

```
InputStream source = connection.getInputStream();
OutputStream target = response.getOutputStream();

int FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
byte[] chunk = new byte[FILE_CHUNK_SIZE]; 
int n =0;
while ( (n = source.read(chunk)) != -1 ) {
    target.write(chunk, 0, n);
}
```

Remember to use try-catch around all this, as there can be many kinds of exceptions thrown in such a transaction. And when you catch the exception, remember to set a response code in your response, which is *not* 200.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't read the input stream from the request object until it runs out of data--buffering it into memory.  In fact, in my experience, that is always how it's done; I can count on the fingers of one hand the number of times I've seen the input stream written to a file instead of being buffered into memory. If you get a content-length header, you can use that as a starting point, but I wouldn't rely on it.  You'll need to protect against too much input, because you don't know what's at the far end of the input stream, and so they server you're contacting you could send so much material that you run out of RAM to process it.

Just keep calling read() until you get a -1. The other read methods can be used for this as well, but you'll add more logic to detect end-of-file.

Comment: I have tried so, but setting Content-Length header of Response does not work after reading all data from an InputStream.

Comment: That's odd--the response and the request are separate objects; changing the request by, for example, reading all its data, shouldn't affect the response at all.

Answer (score -1):

I use this piece of code, no content-length management is done (IOUtils is in commons-io and doesn't create a temporary file) but works with small and large files:

```
public static void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream inputStream, String fileName,
        String contentType) throws IOException {

    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            fileName));

    if (contentType != null) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    }

    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, output);

    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: You could run into problems if not setting the response content length.

Comment: It is possible, it depends on client managing of the response.